# Tableau Desktop: Combine multiple filters into one section to save space

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm a Tableau newbie. I have created a Tableau dashboard. It contains multiple filters which take a lot of space. I want to combine them into one "filter" section, shown in the picture above. How do I do that? Could someone please help?

I saw this on my friend's Tableau dashboard. It combines 3 filters into 1 section, which is very concise. I've been trying to do some digging to see how he did it, but cannot figure it out.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a CONTAINER, in that case vertical container.

You can put all your filters in that container, and then make it Floating (via right click on it).

Once you have it, you can activate the hide/unhide button.